# rearrange bootstrap fields in small size

Tags: html, responsive-design, w3.css

I have made a form with the code below using w3.css, and i want the (send) button to be the last element in small screens and on mobile devices, i do not know how to do that, anyone can help????

```css
  input {
   width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
`    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Push and Pull</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="1">
    <input type="email" placeholder="2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="3">
    <input class="" type="submit" value="send">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="4">
    <input type="email" placeholder="5">
    <input type="text" placeholder="6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>    `
```

Comment: Take a look here https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

put the `<input class="" type="submit" value="send">` in the end of second column

```
<div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
```